# Edit address of autocomplete suggestions in Safari 8

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, safari, address-bar

When you start typing in Safari's "omnibar" you get suggestions based on search results and your bookmarks and history. I often find myself needing to change a small portion of the suggested url; say for instance that the suggested address is `http://foo.com/bar` whereas I want to go directly to `http://foo.com`.

Is there a way to edit the suggested address in place before hitting enter?

Comment: Right arrow will take it to the end of the suggestion as an editable field, you could backspace from there. Also works even if you've down arrow stepped to another suggestion.

Comment: @Tetsujin that allows for editing the search query, if you like. I want to edit the url.

Comment: ? That's exactly what that does, it fills the current autosuggest as an editable URL, rather than going to it. If I want foo.com & the only autosuggest is foo.com/bar, then right arrow fills foo.com/bar as editable text, cursor at the end & I can then backspace/delete the /bar

Comment: @Tetsujin the problem is that the suggestions appear as titles of given webpage, not the url. So if I `foo.com/bar` is in your history then when you start typing in `foo` you get `Foo Industries, Inc.` if that happens to be its title. Then when you press the right arrow and backspace from there, as you say, it lets you edit the search query and not the url, i.e. `Foo Industries, Inc` instead of `http://foo.com/bar`. At least on Safari 8.0.7 on Yosemite.

Comment: hmm… then it may be a prefs setting. I'm on the same version. Maybe prefs/advanced 'show full website address' ? I also have everything off except Google suggestions in the prefs/Search tab.

Comment: @Tetsujin tried mimicking your setup, no luck. Weird.

Comment: @Tetsujin I figured out there are actually two different cases here. One is when the autocompleted suggestion is an url, the other when it's a title. In the first scenario you can indeed "right-arrow" to edit the url, whereas in the second scenario you can't. E.g. try typing `superuser.com` and you'll get a editable url, but if you start typing `edit address of autocomplete` you should get the autocompleted title of this question instead of the url..

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to check tomorrow, on my phone all day today.

Comment: hmm… true - yet it's something I would never type, unless I was searching history specifically, so I guess in that case I'd just have to load the page then edit.